# Is the function $f(x,y)=xy^{\frac{1}{3}}$ differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Is the function $f(x,y)=xy^{\frac{1}{3}}$ differentiable at $(0,0)$?

I'm trying to find the limit of
$$
\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{xy^{\frac{1}{3}}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \;,
$$
but when I use the inequality $x^2+y^2\geq 2|x||y|$, I get stuck at
$$
0 \leq \lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{|x||y|^{\frac{1}{3}}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \leq \lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{(x^2+y^2)|y|^{\frac{-2}{3}}}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}|y|^{\frac{-2}{3}} =\ ?
$$

Comment: It's not even partially differentiable with respect to $y$ for $y=0$.

Comment: please check this question [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052226/is-fx-y-xy2-3-differentiable-at-0-0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052226/is-fx-y-xy2-3-differentiable-at-0-0)